# Why is data format differs from Superset when exported in a CSV?

Tags: excel, csv, export-to-csv, apache-superset

I have a question on data formatting in Apache Superset  - it's defined for a dashboard, and columns are displayed accordingly,

[image]
[image]

but when I export data from dashboard into a csv/excel, format is different, and data is not rounded, can I somehow set a format to it (downloaded file) within Superset so that I don't need to operate any formatting in Excel, or should I change it in my datasourse?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Side note: Excel and CSV are not synonymous.

Comment: Look like the values are correctly formatted as a .2f (rounded to 2 decimals) in Apache Superset, for example you see `228,132.36` but the underlying actual value is `228132.359375` and those raw values are also what is exported to the csv file.

Comment: That's actually strange, because in database there is a setting also rounding my data to .01 format and numbers after it when I download csv data - just appear I guess (because they were not here to begin with).